# Data in php is always NULL after ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I found a lot of questions with this topic, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I try to pass data to a new PHP-page, but i always get NULL.

Here is my JS code:

```
submitHandler: function() {
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'newPhp.php',
        data: { name: "13" },
        success: function(name) {
            console.log(name); // is displayed correctly
            window.location.replace("newPhp.php");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        } //no error occurs for me
    });
}
```

And my PHP-File just does this:

```
$passedName = $_POST["name"];
var_dump($passedName);
```

I want to use this to pass Data from a input form to the server, which sends a confirmation mail.

Comment: `window.location.replace("newPhp.php");` this will create new request which is **get** so you will get null response

Comment: What is your console.log response from the ajax request?

Comment: how can you say it's null in the response.

Comment: I know it is null, because the php-File the browser redirects to shows 'NULL'. The console.log is '13'. B.Desais answer is the solution. I need cookies or pass the parameter in the url.